# mule transformer inside foreach

Tags: mule

I'm using Mule 3.5.
I've got a problem using the bean-builder-transformer inside a foreach tag.
This is my first test:

```
<flow name="mule.activity">
<poll doc:name="Poll">
<fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10000"/>
<db:select config-ref="JSDB" doc:name="Database">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM ACTIVITY WHERE rownum <= 6]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
</poll>
<foreach doc:name="For Each">
<logger message="start id #[payload.'ID']" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="log" />
</foreach>
```

This is the log:

```
[2015-03-18 16:29:23,165] DEBUG: start id 1363230
[2015-03-18 16:29:23,165] DEBUG: start id 1363231
[2015-03-18 16:29:23,165] DEBUG: start id 1363232
[2015-03-18 16:29:23,165] DEBUG: start id 1363233
[2015-03-18 16:29:23,166] DEBUG: start id 1363236
[2015-03-18 16:29:23,166] DEBUG: start id 1363237
```

So everything is ok.

Now I add a bean-builder-transformer inside the foreach tag:

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each">

<logger message="start payload: #[payload]" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="log" />
<logger message="start id #[payload.'ID']" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="log" />

<bean-builder-transformer beanClass="com.jsolutions.mule.IO">
<bean-property property-name="bean_prop_1" evaluator="map-payload" expression="TABLE_FIELD_1" optional="true" />
<bean-property property-name="bean_prop_2" evaluator="map-payload" expression="TABLE_FIELD_2" optional="true" />
... (map all query fields except ID)
</bean-builder-transformer>

<logger message="end payload: #[payload]" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="log" />
<logger
message="end id #[payload.'ID']" level="DEBUG" category="mule.activity" doc:name="log" />

<!-- use the message in order to call a ws service -->
</foreach>
```

This is the log:

```
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,668] DEBUG: start payload: {FIELD_1=004369951, ID=1363230}
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,676] DEBUG: start id 1363230
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,684] DEBUG: end payload: com.jsolutions.mule.IO@67231ee8
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,687] DEBUG: end id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,688] DEBUG: start payload: {FIELD_1=004369951, ID=1363231}
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,688] DEBUG: start id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,690] DEBUG: end payload: com.jsolutions.mule.IO@2bc6e9f1
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,690] DEBUG: end id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,691] DEBUG: start payload: {FIELD_1=004369951, ID=1363232}
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,691] DEBUG: start id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,692] DEBUG: end payload: com.jsolutions.mule.IO@1028e3ab
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,692] DEBUG: end id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,693] DEBUG: start payload: {FIELD_1=TO3925878, ID=1363233}
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,693] DEBUG: start id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,694] DEBUG: end payload: com.jsolutions.mule.IO@6c7af7d6
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,695] DEBUG: end id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,695] DEBUG: start payload: {FIELD_1=TS7066322, ID=1363236}
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,695] DEBUG: start id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,697] DEBUG: end payload: com.jsolutions.mule.IO@7d253a3d
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,697] DEBUG: end id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,698] DEBUG: start payload: {FIELD_1=022245675, ID=1363237}
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,698] DEBUG: start id null
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,699] DEBUG: end payload: com.jsolutions.mule.IO@1712bafb
[2015-03-19 10:08:28,700] DEBUG: end id null
```

I don't understand why, after the first iteration, the id is always "null" ...
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: It makes sense that the "end id" is null (since you alter the payload iwht a transformer) but why isn't the "start id" restored at the next iteration? That's bizarre. Can you also log the payload class at `start` and `end`? But, whoa the `bean-builder-transformer`! I thought this thing didn't make its way into Mule 3 :) It's much easier to use a MEL expression transformer or component to instantiate a bean than using this antiquated puppy. Maybe it's the culprit for this weird behaviour? Maybe it's so old that it doesn't play well with `for-each`?

Comment: Hi David, I've edited my question by adding the payload log. And yes ... I'm pretty sure this weird behaviour is caused by the transformer, but I don't understand why! Anyway, my flow is quite simple: get the db rows, and, for esch row, call a ws service. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are these the payload at `start` or at `end`: can you log both as I asked? Also can you log the payload type instead of its content, as I have asked please?

Comment: I've added start and end to the payload log. How can I get the type of the payload?

Comment: This still doesn't log the payload types. When I see `start payload: {FIELD_1=004369951, ID=1363230}`, I don't know if it's a String or a  Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the start payload is a map (*this is still TBD based on the comments under the question*), use the following expression to retrieve the ID:

```
#[message.payload.ID]
```

Indeed, though accessing a message payload straight with `payload` works in most cases, there are murky circumstances when it doesn't. Using `message.payload` works all the time.